# changescene after timeline

Tags: unity

Is there a way to change the scene after playing a [timeline with the new timeline system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/TimelineSection.html)?

I have 3 scenes in my project. The first scene is where a player interacts with an object to trigger a change to the second scene. The second scene then plays my timeline. When the timeline finished playing I want to change to the 3rd scene.

How can I trigger the scene change at the end of that timeline?

Comment: When you say "timeline", are you referring to the animation timeline?

Comment: no in sequencing

Comment: It might be easier to add that to your question, so others that are reading it can understand better what you are talking about.

Comment: your timeline have a animation? if is true, you can call a script function for change the scene from the end animation